# What is the hash value of each member of the group? Before modding?

Tags: c, hashing

This isn't an actual code related question but it relates to C. We are given:

> Amy's club has grown and now includes the following members: Abel, Abigail, Abraham, Ada, Adam, Adrian, Adrienne, Agnes, Albert, Alex, Alfred, Alice
>
> *Find what value would be computed by Amy's hash function for each member of the group, before modding by the table size?*

I'm not sure what they mean by BEFORE modding, because wouldn't we show the mod equation such as Abel: 4 % 6 = 4, as part of the answer?

> *Now, assume we use Amy's hash function and assign each member to a bucket by simply modding the hash value (obtained from part a) by the number of buckets. Determine how many elements would be assigned to each bucket (assume hashing with chaining) for a hash table of size 6. Do the same for a hash table of size 13.
> c. What are the load factors of these two tables?*

**I would really appreciate an explanation as I'm not sure exactly how to calculate the answers to these problems and haven't found a good example, so a thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: We don't know the answers to these questions either. Show us the hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework. I will not do your homework for you, but here are some nudges in the right direction. I recommend reading up on [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in general.

You have a hash function that is not provided in the question. It is used to place items in a hashtable.

First, you must calculate the hash values. Typically this function will consume an object of a given type and return some sort of integer value using the entire range of the integer type (e.g. 32 bits). This is what the first part of the question is asking: using the hash function, what are the hash values?

To place items in the hashtable, one must next scale those hash values to the size of the table. For example: if the table is size 6, the typical way to do this is take `hash % 6` and that is the index into the hash table, or its "bucket."

The final part of your question is asking for the load factor. That is simply the ratio of elements to the total number of hash table entries (i.e. the array size).

Comment: Yes, this is homework, that's why at the end I was just asking for an explanation, which you have provided so thank you! Now my question is when you have multiple names with the same letters, how do you determine the hash value because Abel would be 4 % 6, but then what would Abigail be, since it also includes an A,b and l in the name? Thanks.

Comment: @androidguy comments are not for asking follow-on questions. You need to look at the hash function. It _should_ consume all letters in the name and transform them somehow, so all of those names give different values. but without the source for the hash function, all we have is speculation.